# Detect hurt players in Minecraft Education Edition

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-education-edition

I'm trying to make a Among Us map in Minecraft Edu, but I can't find a way to detect if the player was hit by another player, because I don't want to show that "*Player* was killed by *Player*", because it would make too obvious that someone was killed. I tried using the instant health effect to detect when the player was healed, but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm not certain if this works in the education edition, but there is a gamerule command to turn off death messages: `/gamerule showdeathmessages false`

Comment: That's exactly what I need, thank you. I should have searched the commands before asking.

Comment: Oh, good! I'm glad I could help. I've gone ahead and turned that comment into an answer if you'd like to mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not a direct answer to your question, your goal can be achieved by turning off the death messages using the command

`/gamerule showdeathmessages false`